# ROC score in gbm package

Tags: r, roc, auc, gbm

I am having trouble calculating ROC score (AUC) using  gbm package. I am working with boosted regression trees. The script I am running is:

```
testing.tc5.lr005 <- gbm.step(data=ModelData, 
gbm.x = 3:4,
gbm.y = 2,
family = "gaussian",
tree.complexity = 5,
learning.rate = 0.005,
bag.fraction = 0.5)
```

It should produce "training data ROC score" and "cross validation ROC score" along with other correlation parameters. I do not get ROC scores. I called `names(testing.tc5.lr005)`. It lists `cv.roc.matrix` but produces the following if I call `testing.tc5.lr005$cv.roc.matrix`:

`[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

I tried calculating ROC AUC by `roc(TestData$TN,predTN)` (TestData~data used for prediction i.e. observed values; predTN~predicted values). It results in `[1]NA`. I have no clue what I am doing wrong, although rest of model seems to be doing good with reasonable testing and CV correlation and SE values.
Any pointers about where I am wrong or an alternate would be really appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: I suspect you are using the `dismo` package? Do you get any output?

Comment: I am using `gbm`. I get all other outputs fine (i.e. deviances, training data correlation, CV correlation, CV SE etc). Its just ROC I am not getting.

Comment: There is no function named `gbm.step` in `gbm`, so the only output you can probably get is `Error: could not find function "gbm.step"`.
Please post the output you get.

Comment: I ran:
`testing.tc5.lr01 <- gbm.step(data=TNTPSumAbundVis1, 
+                             gbm.x = 3:4,
+                             gbm.y = 2,
+                             family = "gaussian",
+                             tree.complexity = 5,
+                             learning.rate = 0.01,
+                             bag.fraction = 0.5)`
and this is the output:
GBM STEP - version 2.9
mean total deviance = 0.815
mean residual deviance = 0.499
estimated cv deviance = 0.637 ; se = 0.093
training data correlation = 0.641 
cv correlation =  0.46 ; se = 0.085
elapsed time -  0.05 minutes

Comment: I apologize such formatting of comment. Just for the record, I am using this paper [http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2656.2008.01390.x/abstract] as reference.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you are using the gbm package in conjunction with the dismo package. As Calimo said, gbm.step does not exist outside dismo.

I can't answer your question of HOW to calculate ROC (I'm no expert--I had the same question and that's how I got here), but I can tell you that dismo won't calculate it. I took a look at the code in the dismo package and it appears that they do not allow ROC calculation for the gaussian family.

Comment: That must be it then, the Gaussian family. Because the paper I am following had Bernoulli distribution type. Secondly, I did not know that gbm is built in conjunction with dismo as I never used dismo as such. I am working on it and will post answer if I could work it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by digging forever into the code and following the threads:

Training data AUC = self.roc = $training.stats$discrimination = $self.statistics$discrimination

Cv AUC score = cv.roc = cv.stats$discrimination.mean = $cv.statistics$discrimination.mean

Se = cv.roc.se = cv.stats$discrimination.se = $cv.statistics$discrimination.se

Usage: model object name + the final bit of code e.g.

```
myobject$self.statistics$discrimination
```

Edit: gbm.step already calculates the values you want, and shows you them, but they're buried within the model object lists.